# displaying php mysql query result with one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

Heres A Sample Table:

```
info table
info_id     name  
1           john  
2           peter
------------------------  
details table  
details_id      log                               date  
1            test log for john                  2013-08-01  
1            another log for john               2013-08-02  
2            test log for peter                 2013-08-02
```

Here's my Sample Query:

```
SELECT info.info_id, info.name, details.details_no, details.log, details.date 
FROM info JOIN details ON details.details_id = info.info_id 
GROUP BY info.info_id
```

And Here's display i want to achieve:

```
john  
1     test log for john            2013-08-01  
1     another test log for john    2013-08-02  

peter  
2     test log for peter           213-08-02
```

I have tried using foreach loop and then execute another foreach loop inside the first loop.

Please Help Guys

Comment: I'm assuming either your table structure in the sample is incomplete or `details.details_no` is a typo, since you don't show a column named `details_no` in the details table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably going to have to take the data and make the array that you want.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $key = $item['name']; // or $item['info_id']
    if (!isset($data[$key])) {
        $data[$key] = array();
    }

    $data[$key][] = $item;
}

// Build your table with the new $data array
```

**EDIT**

This is just an example. As amaster507 points out, if your `name` field isn't unique, you will need to build your array on a unique key. Not terribly different from this, as you could probably just change instances of `$item['name']` to `$item['info_id']`.

Comment: thank you for your quick response, appreciate so much, working good.

Comment: if you use this be warned that you may have values overwritten if `name` is not indexed as unique in your database structure... for instance if you have two johns. Please see my answer below to resolve this problem.

Comment: Very correct @amaster507. I made an edit to my post to point that out

Answer (score 11):

Try making your results into a multidimensional array like below

**Note:** I am assuming that `details.details_no` is a primary key for the `details` table and you want results similar to

```
john  
1     test log for john            2013-08-01  
2     another test log for john    2013-08-02  

peter  
3     test log for peter           213-08-02
```

Which you can retrieve with the following

```
...
$qry = "
    SELECT
        info.info_id,
        info.name,
        details.details_no,
        details.log,
        details.date 
    FROM
        info
        JOIN details ON (details.details_id = info.info_id)
";
$result = mysqli_query($your_db_link,$qry)
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[$row["info_id"]]["name"] = $row["name"];
    $data[$row["info_id"]]["logs"][$row["details_no"]] = array(
        "log"=>$row["log"],
        "date"=>$row["date"],
    );
}
```

Would result in an array like:

```
$data = array(
    "1" => array(
        "name" => "john",
        "logs" => array(
            "1" => array(
                "log" => "test log for john",
                "date" => "2013-08-01",
            ),
            "2" => array(
                "log" => "another test log for john",
                "date" => "2013-08-02",
            ),
        ),
    ),
    "2" => array(
        "name" => "peter",
        "logs" => array(
            "3" => array(
                "log" => "test log for peter",
                "date" => "2013-08-02",
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then you could display like:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($data as $value){
    echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>".$value["name"]."</td></tr>";
    foreach($value["logs"] as $subkey => $subvalue){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$subkey."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$subvalue["log"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$subvalue["date"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Which would result similar to:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>john</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>test log for john</td>
        <td>2013-08-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>another test log for john</td>
        <td>2013-08-02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>test log for peter</td>
        <td>2013-08-02</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first an explanation of the problem.

When you use `GROUP BY`, you no longer get every result as a row, but instead, you get 1 row with *grouped* content, that is, you can use `GROUP BY` to get something like the concatenation of both `log` cells from john, for example.

To  do what you want, remove the `GROUP BY` to get all the rows, and then manually process them.

I recommend you to make easy the job, to use [underscore.php](https://github.com/BlaineSch/Underscore.php) which has a function called `groupBy` which will return an array grouped in subarrays, based on this case, the `info_id` column.

It will be used something like this:

```
$array_with_all_the_rows = $query->fetchAll(); // Or whatever you use to get all rows in 1 array.
$grouped_array = __::groupBy($array_with_all_the_rows, 'info_id');
```

That grouped array will be like this:

```
$grouped_array = Array( 
    "1" => Array(
        "info_id"=> "1", "log"=>"test log for john", "date" => "2013-08-01",
        "info_id"=> "1", "log"=>"another test log for john", "date" => "2013-08-02"
    ), 
    "2" => Array(
        "info_id"=> "2", "log"=>"test log for peter", "date" => "2013-08-02"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To refine Ascherer's answer, you don't need to declare arrays before pushing data into them with `[]` syntax.  If you were using `array_push()` the array would need to be declared as a variable first.

With MySQLi, you can iterate the result set object directly with a `foreach()` and unconditionally use the `info_id` values as keys to group by.

```
$sql = "SELECT info.info_id,
               info.name,
               details.log,
               details.date
        FROM info
        JOIN details ON details.details_id = info.info_id
        ORDER BY info.info_id";

$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row) {
    $data[$row['info_id']][] = $row;
}
```

With PDO, you can use [->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group) to create the same output without manually looping.

When generating your html markup...

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($result as $groupId => $rows) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'><?php echo $rows[0]["name"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $groupId; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['log']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried a foreach with a key/value pair?
can you show us your for loops currently?  a print_r/var_dump for the resulting array will make it easier for someone to help you.

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
  print "Name Row\n";
  for (each display row) {
```

That or as Ascherer suggests make a new multidimensional array that will make nested for loops unnecessary.