# MySQL select photos linked with a single row from different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one with properties (real estate) and other with all photos for all the properties. In table `photos` I have the link of the photo and `ID` of the property. In the table of `properties` I have all information and the `ID`.

I need to query all properties and the photos linked to show results... one property all photos.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979982/displaying-php-mysql-query-result-with-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to get a comma separated list of photos

```
SELECT properties.*, GROUP_CONCAT(photos.photo)
FROM properties
JOIN photos ON properties.id=photos.property_id;
```

Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: you can use GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT photos.photos) to eliminate possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT p.*, p1.* FROM photos p, property p1 WHERE p.property_id = p1.property_id;
```

Comment: It does not work. This query show one row for each photo. I need 1 row for each property with all the photos in array or something... i dont know...

Comment: you don't know what you want, then how can i?

Comment: provide some example in question