# Display Two tables data in Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have following tables

**Author**

```
id | author_name | author_detail | author_bio
```

**books**

```
id | author_id | book_name | book_detail
```

i want to display data in following way

```
Author Name ::
Author Detail ::
books :: 1.book1
         2.book2
         3.book3
         4.book4
```

i have tried following query but didnt worked as per my requirement

```
select * from authors left join books  on author.id=books.author_id
```

i have tried group concat but it gives books name with coma seperate.so i want to books detail in array

```
 select author.author_name,author.author_detail,author.author_bio,group_concat(books.book_name) eft join books  on author.id=books.author_id
```

i am expexting output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Norm

            [books] => Array
                (
                  [0] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 4
                    [book_name] => great wall
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )

                    [1] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 6
                    [book_name] =>new book
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Norm

            [books] => Array
                (
                  [0] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 2
                    [book_name] => amazing star
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )

                    [1] =>Array
                    (
                    [id] => 3
                    [book_name] =>way of journy
                    [created_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    [updated_at] => 2015-09-11 04:45:07
                    )
                )

        )
```

i have checked this question also

[displaying php mysql query result with one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979982/displaying-php-mysql-query-result-with-one-to-many-relationship)

Can any one help me how to display data like above ?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [displaying php mysql query result with one to many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979982/displaying-php-mysql-query-result-with-one-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal.its not duplicate.please read my question

Comment: look at the question, it'll give you the way on how you can solve your problem.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal.ok thank you.but i tried not ogt how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
A.id
A.author_name, 
A.author_detail,
A.author_bio,
B.book_name,
B.created_at,
B.updated_at
FROM books AS B
LEFT JOIN author AS A
ON (A.id=B.author_id)
```

you will get result like this:

```
id | author_name | author_detail | author_bio | book_name
1  | ari         | some detail   | some bio   | book_ari_1
1  | ari         | some detail   | some bio   | book_ari_2
1  | ari         | some detail   | some bio   | book_ari_3
2  | tester      | some detail   | some bio   | book_tester_1
etc..
```

to make array as your expecting result you need to restructure your array result. i will asume your result array will be in `$result` variable

```
$new_result = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($new_result[$value['id']]))
    {
        $new_result[$value['id']] = array(
            'id' => $value['id'],
            'name' => $value['name'],
            'books' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => $value['id'],
                    'book_name' => $value['book_name'],
                    'created_at' => $value['created_at'],
                    'updated_at' => $value['updated_at']
                ),
            )
        )
    }
    else
    {
        $new_result[$value['id']]['id'] = $value['id'];
        $new_result[$value['id']]['name'] = $value['name'];
        $new_result[$value['id']]['books'][] = array(
            'id' => $value['id'],
            'book_name' => $value['book_name'],
            'created_at' => $value['created_at'],
            'updated_at' => $value['updated_at']
        );
    }
}

the result will look like your expected. but the key number will be formated as id.
```

to reset key of `$new_result` as increment number you need to get only value use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function

```
 $new_result = array_values($new_result);
```

Comment: hi this will return separate array like this  [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => david
            [books] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [book_name] => book2
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: the id inside books is your author_id or book_id? if book_id you need to select book_id first. and parse to array from $value['book_id']

Comment: .thank you .your answer solved my question.thanks a lot.

Comment: ,is it good practice to store data like above or group concat  is good ? which is better ?

Comment: if you set result with group_concat then it will make mistake when the title of book has a comma(",") im not sure if the title of book allow comma. by the way you can define separator group_concat to another separator. but the result is limited by default to 1024. you can change the default length. i can't say the current algorithm is better or not. both of them are working. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95312/discussion-between-ari-djemana-and-tester).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with your first query...but you'd have to check the author_id inside the record loop and show the author details only whenever the value changed (by comparing it with a value stored in a variable)...otherwise only show the book details.

So your code might (very roughly) look like this:

```
$query = "select whatever whatever...";
$records = $database->Execute($query);
foreach ($records as $fields) {
    if ($fields['id'] != $previous_id) echo "Author ...";
    echo "Book whatever whatever ...";
    $previous_id = $fields['id'];
}
```

A more straightforward (although slightly longer) way would be to have a second query: a sub-query.  And it would take place inside the loop through the results of the first (outer) query.  So your outer query gets the authors and, after you show the author details, you have this separate query for books of the author...and you have a loop-within-the-outer-loop to show the details of each book.

So your code (very roughly) looks something like this:

```
$query = "select id, author_name, whatever from author";
$author_records = $database->Execute($query);
foreach ($author_records as $fields) {
    echo "Author: {$fields['author_name']} whatever <br/>";
    $subquery = "select whatever from books where id = whatever";
    $book_records = $database->Execute($subquery);
    foreach ($book_records as $otherfields) {
        echo "Book whatever whatever";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in php no need to go in query itself but take both data in separate query i.e. books and author data

Remember i assumed `$result` as authors data and `$result2` as books data

```
$item=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id=$row['id'];        
        $item[$id]['name']=$row['name'];
        $item[$id]['id']=$row['id'];
        $item[$id]['books']=array();
        $temp=array();
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
         {
           if($id==$row1['author_id'])
           {
             $temp['id']=$row1['id'];
             $temp['book_name']=$row1['book_name'];
             $temp['created_at']=$row1['created_at'];
             $temp['updated_at']=$row1['updated_at'];
             array_push($item['id']['books'],$temp);
           }           
         }
    }
```

Now here id is formatted as author's id. To get like array keys you can use `array_values($item)`